# How to strip all non-English characters from varchar in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to replace non-English letters from the database. The following does not work, it's retuning the same as input..

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR (100)= 'AlfonsínSomoza' 
DECLARE @pos INTEGER

WHILE PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%',@string) > 0  
BEGIN
   SET @pos = PATINDEX('%[^a-z]%',@string)
   SET @string = REPLACE(@string,SUBSTRING(@string,@pos,1),'')
END
```

It returns:

```
AlfonsínSomoza
```

But I need

```
AlfonsinSomoza
```

Comment: what we can see you are not removing character from your string you are replacing `í` with `i`

Comment: Define "English characters". Is `æ` one?

Answer (score 3):

By selecting the value with another collation (code page 125x) the accents can be removed. For example

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR (100)= 'AlfonsínSomoza' 

select @string COLLATE  SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1251_CS_AS ;
```

Answer (score 2):

`SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI`     Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-insensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive for Unicode Data, SQL Server Sort Order 124 on Code Page 1253 for non-Unicode Data

```
SELECT 'AlfonsínSomoza' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI
```

*This work only if you are not using a unicode string, so cast it as varchar first if you have a unicode string.*